# Is there a way to list packages from date when they entered Debian archive?

Tags: debian, grep, apt, package-management, regular-expression

I have asked numerous questions about [apt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bapt%5D%20user%3Ame) and [package management](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpackage-management%5D%20user%3Ame) in the past. Not breaking with the tradition here's one more. After doing

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Or/and

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Is there a way to get listing of packages (descending) from when they entered in the Debian archive ?

Something similar to [the new added packages](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/main/newpkg) sorted by age, but on the desktop . Let's say all packages which entered Debian archive and are in the `/var/lib/apt/lists/` database.

Btw, I do regularly do `$ sudo aptitude forget-new` otherwise listing of new packages becomes too large to be useful in any way.

Looking forward to know.

Update :- I use zsh and here's my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
[$] cat /etc/apt/sources.list

     1   #### Debian stretch #########
     2  deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
     3  deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
     4  
     5   #### Debian unstable #########
     6  deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib non-free
     7  deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian unstable main contrib 
     8  
     9   #### Debian experimental #########
    10  deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib 
    11  deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian experimental main contrib
    12  
    13   ##### Debian Debug packages #######
    14  deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ stretch-debug main
    15  deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ unstable-debug main
    16  deb http://debug.mirrors.debian.org/debian-debug/ experimental-debug main
    17  
    18  ######## Third party repos #######
    19  deb https://riot.im/packages/debian/ stretch main
    20  
    21  ########## Non-free ########
    22  #deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free
```

I am looking for package listing of all 'NEW' amd64 packages from last 3 months, not just packages installed on my system.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve but I suspect it would be better solved by monitoring some web page or mailing list.

Answer (score 4):

The information stored locally isn’t sufficient to build such a list: none of the files used to index repositories lists the date at which a package first became available.

The closest you can get, as far as I can see, is the first date mentioned in **installed** packages’ changelogs, which gives some approximation to the date at which the corresponding *source* package entered the archive. (The source aspect is significant since `aptitude`’s notion of new packages is based on binary packages.)

This can certainly be improved:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /usr/share/doc/*/changelog.Debian.gz; do
    package=${file:15}
    package=${package%%/*}
    echo -n "$package "
    date -d "$(zgrep "\\-\\- .* <.*>  .*" "${file}"|tail -n 1|awk 'BEGIN { FS="  " } { for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) { if (i > 2) printf " "; printf "%s", $i } }')" +%s
done | sort -k2,2nr -k1
```

This outputs the names of all your locally-installed packages, with the earliest date in their changelog expressed as the number of seconds since the epoch, sorted by increasing age.

In Debian 9, `aptitude` allows finer-grained purging of the new packages list, which helps make it manageable and useful.

To obtain the information you’re actually after, assuming you don’t have access to the indexes on `master.debian.org`, you’ll probably have to parse the archives of [`debian-devel-changes`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-changes/). These include all changes made to Debian packages, old and new, but you can easily filter the changes corresponding to the introduction of a package: those are the only ones which repeat the suite (“unstable, unstable”; compare [`bdist-nsi`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-changes/2017/05/msg00034.html) and [`node-typescript`](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel-changes/2017/05/msg00033.html) for example).

Comment: I am unable to figure out how to use the output generated, any help with that.

Comment: See my update; that script isn’t what you’re really after though, given your update.