# How to get the list of the newcomers packages in debian?

Tags: debian, command-line, package-management

Is there any command line tool to list the newly added package in debian?

Answers accepted for debian stable, testing or Sid (because it is a highly active release)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`aptitude` keeps track of new packages, and you can list them using

```
aptitude search '~N'
```

They show up in the “New Packages” section in the UI.

To clear the list of new packages, run

```
aptitude forget-new
```

or press <kbd>f</kbd> in the UI; you can also specify [a subset of new packages to be “forgotten”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364581/86440).

The set of packages considered here will depend on the repositories you have configured: if your system only tracks Debian 10, you’ll only see new packages in Debian 10 (generally speaking, new kernels after an ABI bump); if your system is configured with the unstable repositories (whether or not it actually tracks unstable), you’ll see new packages in unstable.

To track specific suites, you can use the RSS feeds: [unstable](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/main/newpkg?format=rss), [stable](https://packages.debian.org/stable/main/newpkg?format=rss) etc. (but these only list the last seven days’ worth of updates).